# What exactly is this neural network called?

Tags: python, neural-network

To get started I have seen this neural network when I was first learning about them. I've been trying to figure out what it's called. But I'm not sure if it's called something else or if it doesn't have a name.

```py
from numpy import array, dot, exp, random


class Neural_Network:
    def __init__(self):
        random.seed(1)
        self.sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
        self.bias = 1
        self.inputs = array([
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1]
        ])
        self.weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1))
        self.outputs = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

        def train():
            for i in range(20000):
                self.input = self.inputs
                self.actual_output = self.outputs
                self.output = self.sigmoid(dot(self.input, self.weights) + self.bias)

                self.error = self.actual_output - self.output

                self.adjustment = dot(self.input.T, self.error * (self.output * (1 - self.output)))
                self.weights += self.adjustment

            self.new_inputs = array([1, 0, 0])
            self.output = self.sigmoid(
                dot(self.new_inputs, self.weights) + self.bias)
        train()
        print(self.output)


neural_network = Neural_Network()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **Sigmoid Neuron**.
It is not really a network but a single block of a NN.
You can read about it [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Book%3A_Neural_Networks_and_Deep_Learning_(Nielsen)/01%3A_Using_neural_nets_to_recognize_handwritten_digits/1.03%3A_Sigmoid_neurons)